# Protractor simple test works 50% of the time

Tags: angular, typescript, protractor

I'm trying to setup some simple ***`protractor`*** tests to try E2E tests with `Angular2`. I'm using the following versions : (**v4.4.3 NG2** / **v5.1.2 protractor**).

I'm also using the latest `@angular/cli` version with the premade **protractor.conf.js** file.

Here is a simple test I've setup with my existing application.

---

```
import { browser, by, element } from 'protractor';

describe('Protractor testing suite with TypeScript', () => {
  beforeAll(() => {
    browser.get('/');  

    // Add logging.
    browser.manage().logs().get('browser').then(function (browserLog) {
      console.log('log: ' + require('util').inspect(browserLog));
    });
  });

  describe('Protractor first test suite', function () {
    it('should navigate to the map', function () {
      const navigationMapButton = element(by.id('general.menu.esri_maps'));
      navigationMapButton.click();

      // Testing the navigation to another page here (The page is lazy-loaded, that might be linked)
      browser.wait(() => {
        return browser.getCurrentUrl().then((url) => {
          console.log(url);
          return url.includes('esrimaps');
        })
      })
        .then((resolved) => {
          expect(resolved).toBeTruthy();
        });
    });
  });
})
```

And the main issue is that 50% of the time, the test fails, and the other time, it works. Here are the following logs :

---

**Successful test log:**

```
[13:48:14] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[13:48:14] I/direct - Using ChromeDriver directly...
Spec started
log: []
http://localhost:4200/pages/dashboard
http://localhost:4200/pages/dashboard
http://localhost:4200/pages/dashboard
http://localhost:4200/pages/dashboard
http://localhost:4200/pages/dashboard
http://localhost:4200/pages/dashboard
http://localhost:4200/pages/dashboard
http://localhost:4200/pages/dashboard
http://localhost:4200/pages/dashboard
http://localhost:4200/pages/dashboard
http://localhost:4200/pages/dashboard
http://localhost:4200/pages/dashboard
http://localhost:4200/pages/dashboard
http://localhost:4200/pages/dashboard
http://localhost:4200/pages/dashboard
http://localhost:4200/pages/dashboard
http://localhost:4200/pages/dashboard
http://localhost:4200/pages/maps/esrimaps

  Protractor testing suite with TypeScript

    Protractor first test suite
      √ should navigate to the map

Executed 1 of 1 spec SUCCESS in 6 secs.
[13:48:23] I/launcher - 0 instance(s) of WebDriver still running
[13:48:23] I/launcher - chrome #01 passed
```

---

**Failure test log :**

```
[13:49:37] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[13:49:37] I/direct - Using ChromeDriver directly...
Spec started
log: []
http://localhost:4200/pages/dashboard
http://localhost:4200/pages/dashboard
http://localhost:4200/pages/dashboard
http://localhost:4200/pages/dashboard
http://localhost:4200/pages/dashboard
http://localhost:4200/pages/dashboard
http://localhost:4200/pages/dashboard
http://localhost:4200/pages/dashboard
http://localhost:4200/pages/dashboard
http://localhost:4200/pages/dashboard
http://localhost:4200/pages/dashboard
http://localhost:4200/pages/dashboard
http://localhost:4200/pages/dashboard
http://localhost:4200/pages/dashboard
http://localhost:4200/pages/dashboard
http://localhost:4200/pages/dashboard
http://localhost:4200/pages/dashboard
http://localhost:4200/pages/dashboard
http://localhost:4200/pages/dashboard
http://localhost:4200/pages/dashboard

  Protractor testing suite with TypeScript

    Protractor first test suite
      × should navigate to the map

   ...

**************************************************
*                    Failures                    *
**************************************************

1) Protractor testing suite with TypeScript Protractor first test suite should navigate to the map
  - Failed: Timed out waiting for asynchronous Angular tasks to finish after 11 seconds. This may be because the current page is not an Angular application. Please see t
he FAQ for more details: https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/timeouts.md#waiting-for-angular

Executed 1 of 1 spec (1 FAILED) in 17 secs.
[13:49:57] I/launcher - 0 instance(s) of WebDriver still running
[13:49:57] I/launcher - chrome #01 failed 1 test(s)
[13:49:57] I/launcher - overall: 1 failed spec(s)
[13:49:57] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 1
```

---

**Additionnal information :**

- When failing, obviously it's because it timeouts when trying to navigate, but on the web driver instance, it successfully navigate every time on the `click()`. It seems obvious that it somehow loses track of what is happening, but I can't point out what is making this happen...
- There is a loader between the loading time, so maybe it's linked ? (I'm using the NG2-admin template tailored to my needs : https://github.com/akveo/ngx-admin)
- As I said before, the **dashboard** and the **map** are lazy-loaded, so maybe it's linked ?
- I've seen this link : https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/timeouts.md about timeouts, but I've no idea which use case I should implement... Do I really need to change my code everywhere to use `zone.js` for async tasks ? It seems really annoying to change everything just because of that issue...

Comment: make your timeout longer than 11 seconds - https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/timeouts.md#timeouts-from-webdriver

Comment: I already tried using `allScriptsTimeout: 18000,` it doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, so actually I used the worst possible example to try my tests on. I though it could be because of the lazy-loading or other mecanisms like that, but not at all : 
My map is an **Esri** map using the **ArcGIS JS API**, which is served through an angular-esri-loader library because of the ArcGIS JS API being served through Dojo.

Therefore, it is not exactly an angular context, and I had to use `browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);` to make it work.